# How do I change hours-per-day without affecting existing tasks?

Tags: ms-project

I have a list of tasks, each measured in days. The hours-per-day setting on the project is incorrect. When I update it, the tasks change accordingly.

My problem is that it's only the hours-per-day that is wrong; the length of each task is correct in terms of days, so I do not want it to change.

8 hours per day:

```
Example task - 2 days
```

Change to 7 hours per day:

```
Example task - 2.29 days //undesired
```

There's many tasks so updating them individually is obviously impractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the task duration column to excel and multiplied by appropriate factor to undo the operation project applied, then copied it back.

Answer (score 1):

Change your task to fix duration.

Comment: Indeed. However there's many (100s) task; such a thing would be laborious. However, thinking about it, I could use excel.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. As an alternative for future reference, you could have multi-selected all the tasks, then changed the task type to Fixed Duration from the Task Information dialog. That will change all the tasks at the same time.

Comment: @dlongman can you expand on that? They are already fixed-duration auto-schedule. If I make any changes there it will make all the tasks the same duration (they're dissimilar size).

Comment: If the tasks are already fixed duration are you sure you are seeing the task duration increasing when you change the number of hours per day or are you looking at the effort column? The duration should not change for fixed duration tasks but the effort probably will.you